# Criar cabeçalho de tabela dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar um cabeçalho dinâmico baseado num array que a função recebe, a estrutura que tentei, e não funcionou, é a seguinte:

```
function createDynamicHeader(columns) {

          var table = document.querySelector('#table_teste');

          var header = table.createTHead();

          header.createElement('tr');

          for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
              var header_row = header.createElement('th');
              header_row.innerHTML(columns[i]);
          }

      }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table_teste" class="table table-bordered"></table>
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
function createDynamicHeader(columns) {
  var table = document.querySelector('#table_teste');

  // Cria um elemento <thead> vazio e o adiciona à tabela:
  var header = table.createTHead();

  // Cria um elemento <tr> vazio dentro do header da tabela:
  var row = header.insertRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    // Insere uma nova célula (<td>) dentro do elemento <tr>:
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    // Adiciona algum texto na nova célula:
    cell.innerHTML = columns[i];
  }
}

// Chama a função para testar.
createDynamicHeader(['Coluna TD 1', 'Coluna TD 2', 'Coluna TD 3'])
```

```html
<table id="table_teste" class="table table-bordered"></table>
```

Mas, o seu código não estava dando certo por causa desses pontos:

- Em `header.createElement('tr')`: O elemento `thead` não tem um método `createElement()`, você tem que usar o método do objeto `document` e depois adicionar o elemento `tr` criado no documento ao elemento `thead`; e você não estava armazenando a referência ao elemento `tr` criado, para depois adicionar as colunas a ele;
- Em `header_row = header.createElement('th')`: Mesma coisa que o anterior;
- Em `header_row.innerHTML(columns[i])`: Você estava usando `innerHTML` como um método, mas ela é uma propriedade, então você deveria fazer `header_row.innerHTML = columns[i]`.

Segue a mesma solução usando o seu código original:

```js
function createDynamicHeader(columns) {
  var table = document.querySelector('#table_teste');

  var header = table.createTHead();

  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  header.appendChild(row);

  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var cell = document.createElement('th');
    cell.innerHTML = columns[i];
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
}

createDynamicHeader(['Coluna TH 1', 'Coluna TH 2', 'Coluna TH 3'])
```

```html
<table id="table_teste" class="table table-bordered"></table>
```